# AWS SAM functions no longer using latest layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I'm having an issue with my SAM deployments where it appears that the latest function versions are no longer using the latest layer version. I'm pretty sure it might have started when I added `AutoPublishAlias: live` to the SAM template to enable concurrency because that's where I would have started using versions. I'll post my relevant template code:

```yaml
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: python3.9
    CodeUri: functions/
    AutoPublishAlias: live
    DeploymentPreference:
      Type: AllAtOnce
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    Layers:
      - !Ref SrcLayer
    Timeout: 10
    Environment:
      Variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: !Ref Environment

Resources:
  SrcLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: SrcLayer
      Description: Python dependencies
      ContentUri: .
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.9
      LicenseInfo: 'MIT'
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.9
      BuildArchitecture: x86_64

  RandomFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: xxx.zzz
      Role: !GetAtt [FunctionRole, Arn]
      FunctionName:
        !Join
          - '-'
          - - 'function-random'
            - !Ref Environment
      Events:
        RandomEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /path/{id}
            Method: get
            RequestParameters:
              - method.request.path.id:
                  Required: true
            RestApiId:
              Ref: MainAPI
```

First project using SAM so there's probably a lot I'm not quite understanding. Do I now need to point each function version to the latest layer?

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix eventually. I first updated the `transform` line in my template.yaml from this:

```yaml
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

to this:

```yaml
Transform:
  - AWS::LanguageExtensions
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

per [this](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/2533) github issue. To quote the issue:

*"Some properties have limited support for intrinsic functions (e.g. Fn::If, Fn::FindInMap, etc.).
Using unsupported intrinsic functions in such properties can cause issues with deployment."*

I then had an issue with the deploy failing because ApiGateway::Stage already exists...I just deleted the cloudformation stack and redeployed the sam project via `sam build`, `sam deploy`.

I get the feeling that's an unsatisfying but easy fix for most sam issues.